# Is there a notation for the given matrix manipulation?

Tags: matrices, notation

For an $m \times m$ matrix $M$, is there a notation which states that for all elements $v_{ij}$, for $i=j$, are replaced by zeros? More simpler: is there a notation which states to replace the diagonal with zeros?

$M = \begin{bmatrix}
v_{11} & \dots & v_{1m} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
v_{m1} & \dots & v_{mm}\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$
$\rightarrow$
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \dots & v_{1m} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
v_{m1} & \dots & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 5):

If you write $\odot$ for the [Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) (entriwise) product of matrices, then your desired operation is
$M(A) = A - I\odot A$, since $I\odot A$ has the same diagonal as $A$, but it has zeroes everywhere else.

Comment: Similarly, one could define a constant _off-diagonal matrix_ with zeros on the diagonal and ones elsewhere, i.e. $\,F=J-I.\;$ Then $\;M(A) = F\odot A\quad$

Answer (score 1):

It is called a hollow matrix. I do not know of any special notation for it.

See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_matrix